# How do I figure out what is using up all my data?

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring, background-data

I typically only use between 1GB and 2GB per month of data. However, this month I was notified that I had exceeded my 4GB limit. I increased the limit to 7GB and within 4 days that was exceeded. I've now shut off all cellular data. When I look in Settings > Data Usage > Cellular Data Usage it shows 7.25GB of data used by Android OS. If I tap on Android OS it lists a bunch of apps like com.qti.service.colorservice and com.quicinc.cne.CNEService.CNEServiceApp. I don't know if this list is sorted by which service/app used the most data and there's no more detail I can attain by tapping on the apps listed under Android OS.

Since I have dates and times for some of the largest downloads (868MB on March 27, 12:57AM for example), is there somewhere in the file system where I can see a list of IP addresses connected to and their timestamps to perhaps narrow down who/what is sucking up all my data?

Is there a more thorough way of wiping the phone than a factory reset?

Anybody seen this before and have any suggestions?

Comment: Not entirely sure if you can retrace those IP-data usage statistics , however there is a handy app (Network Connections) which tacks live connections and maps IP - data usage so allows tracking which apps are online and how much bandwidth is it using, also for other statistics. In addition I also recommend an app similar to 3g watchdog which keeps a history of data usage in your apps and allows per - app data restriction.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Cool, I'll check those out. I just heard from someone on xda that the Automatic System Updates switch under Settings > Developer Options doesn't work. So I think my phone has been repeatedly trying to download the March security update.